# How to handle a lot of PDF generations in a Laravel based application and send them by email

Tags: php, performance, laravel, pdf, cron

I'm just curious how would you handle a scenario where a lot of PDF's has to be generated on the server and be send to the user by email. You're not able to temper with the PDF because it needs to be 100% secure or close to that number.

For example the PDF contains the order you just made in a webshop, proof of purchase or something like that.

The application will have a lot of concurrent users. For this question I will use Laravel as a base platform for the web application.

I had the idea of running a cron job at night that will generate all this PDF's at once and send per e-mail.

What is considered best practise in this scenario?

Comment: You could create a basic HTML template and you build it with their values, then you add a button "Print to PDF" and on click it calls `window.print()`. I'm pretty sure at least Chrome and Firefox support the print method, although I am not sure about other browsers so you might have to dig deeper into this one! You could solve this problem by checking for the browser and if it doesn't support print, you can send a request to the server and generate a PDF with that as well. Not sure why you want to create them all at once though... Can't you create them on the fly?

Comment: @AntoniuLivadariu Yes I'm aware of using client side PDF's. But I want to email the PDF's to the user instead of letting them browse to the website again. So for this to work I have to generate the pdf at first on server -> email PDF -> delete PDF in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example the PDF contains the order you just made in a webshop, proof of purchase or something like that.

Given that these will presumably occur throughout the day, [a queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues) may be a better solution than a cron. Every time someone does an action that'd require a PDF, fire off a queue job. A background process will check for queued jobs and process them.

This avoids having a giant backlog, protects you in the case a cron fails, and gets PDFs out to the clients in a more timely fashion.